# Injecting concrete repository into base class

Tags: c#, .net

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<TId>
{
    public TId Id { get; }
}
        
public abstract class CarBase : BaseEntity<long>
{
    // ...
}

public class Honda : CarBase
{
    // ...
}
```

I have a base handler `HandleCarBase` which accepts repository with generic

```
public interface ICarRepository<T> where T : CarBase
{
    Task<long> Add(T car);
    ....
}

public interface IHondaRepository : ICarRepository<Honda>
{
}

public abstract class HandleCarBase
{
    protected HandleSomething(ICarRepository<CarBase> repository)
    {
        Repository = repository;
    }
 
    protected ICarRepository<CarBase> Repository { get; }
}

public class HondaHandler : HandleCarBase
{
   public HondaHandler(IHondaRepository repository) 
  : base(repository) //error
   {
   }
}
```

But I get this error:

> HondaHandler.cs cannot convert from 'MyProject.IHondaRepository' to 'MyProject.ICarRepository'

Not sure why this not working cause concrete `IHondaRepository` implements `ICarRepository<CarBase>` in the base class, and `Honda` entity used in the `IHondaRepository` is a `CarBase` class. I'm open to suggestions on how to refactor this.

I tried to pass `ICarRepository<Honda>` instead of `IHondaRepository` in the `HondaHandler`, but that didn't change anything

Comment: `IHondaRepository` derives from `ICarRepository<Honda>`, which is not assignable to `ICarRepository<CarBase>`. Same reason you cannot assign `IList<Lion>` to a variable of type `IList<Animal>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your generic type definition should include covariant modifier `out T`:

```
public interface ICarRepository<out T> where T : CarBase
{
    Task<long> Add(CarBase car);
}
```

See [Covariance and Contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance) for more details.